# How is it possible to change just the directionality of the controller?

Tags: flutter

I am using the Persian language in my flutter app. so, the directionality of my pages is right to left. when I want to enter the password, my controller doesn't display it properly.
I want the numbers entered in the password field to be displayed in a left-to-right format.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property called **textDirection** in the TextField constructor, try setting it to **ltr** and see if it fixes your issue.

```
TextField(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)
```

There is also **textAlign**, but this only affects the position of the text not the direction of typing. It might help you to visually change the position of the text.

Comment: Keep the TextDirection to TextDirection.ltr. And change the textAlign to TextAlign.right. Like this: **TextField(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, textAlign:TextAlign.right)** . If this works, could you please mark my answer as accepted?